# Jquery show / hide on click and default function

Tags: html, jquery, onclick

I'm very new to Jquery and I need your help!
I'm trying to make a default option1 to be displayed automatically and I don't really know how to get it done. 
the three buttons in the HTML code should be used like a switch and each will show other other content inside a div. but, I can't find the correct way to show the first option as a default option to display even without clicking the buttons.

I want the content from the "full" div to be displayed as default content first and i need it to be shown / hidden using the buttons.

Please, help me solve this in the right way.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="option1">full</button>
  <button type="button" id="option2">empty</button>
  <button type="button" id="option3">new</button>
</div>      

<div id="show-div">
    <div id="full">
        <p>This full should be default</p>
    </div>
    <div id="empty">
        <p>This is empty</p>                
    </div>
    <div id="new">
        <p>this is another option</p>               
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button[type="button"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'option1') {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').show();
            $('#units').show();  
            $('#empty').hide();
            $('#new').hide();           
       }

        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option2') {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').hide();
            $('#empty').show();
            $('#new').hide();   
       }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option3') {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').hide();
            $('#empty').hide();
            $('#new').show();   
       }
       else {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').show();
            $('#default').show();
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#empty, #new").hide();
    $('button[type="button"]').click(function () {
        $('#show-div').show();
        $('#' + this.innerHTML).show().siblings().hide();
        $('#units').show();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kegg4Lec/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try it as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button[type="button"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'option1') {
       $('div').not(".btn-group").hide();
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').show();
            $('#units').show();  

       }

        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option2') {
           $('div').not(".btn-group").hide();
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#empty').show();
       }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option3') {
           $('div').not(".btn-group").hide();
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#new').show();   
       }
       else {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').show();
            $('#default').show();
       }
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bmurj45/)

[Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bmurj45/1/)

Comment: Your's is hiding buttons too. I guess that's not required.

Answer (score 0):

Add display none to the divs you want to hide

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="option1">full</button>
  <button type="button" id="option2">empty</button>
  <button type="button" id="option3">new</button>
</div>      

<div id="show-div">
    <div id="full">
        <p>This full should be default</p>
    </div>
    <div id="empty" style="display:none">
        <p>This is empty</p>                
    </div>
    <div id="new"  style="display:none">
        <p>this is another option</p>               
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0ofnbmed/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css or jquery like below

CSS

```
#empty #new{display:none;}
```

**[DEMO with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/0ofnbmed/3/)**

OR using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   //hide empty and new
   $('#empty').hide();
   $('#new').hide();   

   $('button[type="button"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'option1') {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').show();
            $('#units').show();  
            $('#empty').hide();
            $('#new').hide();           
       }

        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option2') {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').hide();
            $('#empty').show();
            $('#new').hide();   
       }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option3') {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').hide();
            $('#empty').hide();
            $('#new').show();   
       }
       else {
            $('#show-div').show(); 
            $('#full').show();
            $('#default').show();
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

**[DEMO with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/0ofnbmed/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try like below...

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#show-div').show(); 
         $('#full').show();
         $('#empty').hide();
         $('#new').hide();    

  $('button[type="button"]').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'option1') {
        $('#show-div').show(); 
        $('#full').show();
        $('#units').show();  
        $('#empty').hide();
        $('#new').hide();           
   }

    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option2') {
        $('#show-div').show(); 
        $('#full').hide();
        $('#empty').show();
        $('#new').hide();   
   }
    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'option3') {
        $('#show-div').show(); 
        $('#full').hide();
        $('#empty').hide();
        $('#new').show();   
   }
   else {
        $('#show-div').show(); 
        $('#full').show();
        $('#default').show();
   }
 });
 });
```

Here is the fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/w9p5ck6o/